# How can I make these eyes move?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript-2

I am using Flash(as2 or 3 doesn't matter). I would like to know the match behind the moving eyes or possibilities to use default flash tools to make eyes move.

**Eyes:**

[image: Eyes]

My biggest concern is eye shapes. They are not circural not ellipse. My second concern is the lightning on puppils. Can someone give me a hint how should I implement that?

**My method**
I would cut the puppils out as well as lightning. Then use these formulas for rotate the puppils around the origin point(center of eyes):

```
x = x * cos(angle) - y * sin(angle)
y = x * sin(angle) + y * cos(angle)
```

That would work well if eyes would be circular but not in this case, so I could modify the **y** formula to give more elliptic rotation.

Any advice is really appreciated. Thank you.

**CONCLUSION**
Based on **ezekielDFM** advice, I made the eyes move with a classical tween(360 frames). It worked perfectly. I did 4 tweens for the eyes, to be more circural movement. Then calculated the angle between mouse and the eye with Math.atan2(diffY,diffX) and did gotoAndStop(angle). Worked like a charm. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a timeline animation of the eye on a guide path moving in a circle around the edge of the eye. Make the animation 360 frames long and start it with the eye roughly at 0 degrees. Check the angle of the mouse from center point of the eye to get a angle and between 0 and 360 degrees. Finally, `gotoAndStop` the frame from the angle value.

Comment: No problemo. If you want to make it more smooth you could even use a tweening engine with "animate to frame" support, such as Greensock. The only tricky area would be going from 360 to 0 (or vice versa), you would have to apply some specific logic there.